# o["postmore"] is not iterable

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to transform created_time from CST to `ISOString(ex:2019-02-22T17:43:05.000Z)`, so i need to get created_time.
But I have the question. When I use `for(let...of...){}` , I get the error

> "o.postmore is not iterable".

How to fixed the codes to get `created_time` and transform the time?

```
{
    "data": [
    {
        "text1": "123",
        "desc": "xyz",
        "postmore": [
        {
            "name": "haha",
            "created_time": "2018-08-22 18:30:01 CST+0800"
        },
        {
            "name": "gogo",
            "created_time": "2018-08-22 18:30:01 CST+0800" 
        }]
    },
    {
        "text1": "123",
        "desc": "hjk",
        "postmore": [
        {
            "name": "haha",
            "created_time": "2018-08-23 18:30:01 CST+0800"
        },
        {
            "name": "gogo",
            "created_time": "2018-08-23 18:30:01 CST+0800"
        }]
    }]
}


this.http.get(url).subscribe(res =>{

    this.testapi = res["data"];

    for (let o of this.testapi){

        o["text1"] = parseInt(o["text1"]);

        for(let os of o["postmore"]){
            os["created_time"] = new Date().toISOString();
            console.log(os["created_time"]);
        }

    };
)
```

Comment: It does work in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x8kr7p3t/). You might want to check what `o["postmore"]` is. Also you might want to pass `os["created_time"]` into the `Date` constructor/

Comment: Yes, but Chrome console show error text "o.postmore is not iterable".  And can't show each os["created_time"]

Comment: Yes, I intend to tell you that you could log `o["postmore"]` and check what it is before you proceed to the loop, it can be null which can cause the issue

Comment: it's not Null, it show ` {
            "name": "haha",
            "created_time": "2018-08-22 18:30:01 CST+0800"
        },
        {
            "name": "gogo",
            "created_time": "2018-08-22 18:30:01 CST+0800" 
        } `

Comment: try to declare type of o['postmore'] as array:

let list: object[] = o['postmore'];
for(let os of list){
            os["created_time"] = new Date().toISOString();
            console.log(os["created_time"]);
        }